# java and Arithmetic Operators and Increment

Tags: java, increment, operator-keyword

It is one of the simple operations and I do not understand why and I just save it, but this bothers me, so I want to understand why?

```
int a = 2;
int b = 4;
int c = 10;
a = b++;
System.out.println(a);
a = ++b;   
System.out.println(a);
```

This process ++ I did not understand how it works. In this case, the output is 4 and 6

But I only added 1 and the result was an added 2

In the beginning, she only took the value 4 without added any thing, then in the second output, she added 2

If you put the code in the sixth line a = ++c, the output will be by adding 1, not 2, to c.

so Some help to understand please.

On the other hand, since = is an assignment, I imagine that the result will preserve the last number, and now if I modify the code as follows:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 4;
int c = 10;
a = b++;
System.out.println(a);
a = ++c;   
System.out.println(a);
a = ++b;
System.out.println(a);
```

Here the output will be

```
4
11
6
```

I did not expect this either, as the last output should have been 5, not 6.

So I would like some help, please, so that I can understand and not just memorize.

Comment: In the case `a = b++;`, it adds 1 to `b`, but it copies the OLD value into `a`.  Thus, `a` will be 4, but `b` will be `5`.  When you do `a = ++b;`, it bumps `b` by 1 BEFORE it does the copy.   `b` becomes 6, so that's what is stored in `a`.  The original value of `a` is never used.  Your second example bumps `b` TWICE.  It becomes 6.

Comment: okay but   a = b++;   why a become b by 1, What is the benefit of this operation that you performed?

Comment: I think I understood somewhat, and this means that a = b++ are two operations, not just one operation. One of the operations is assigning b to a, and the other is adding 1?

Comment: `a = b++;`  -> `a = b; b = b + 1;`, whereas `a = ++b;` -> `b = b + 1; a = b;`.

Comment: thank u all i understand now

Comment: yes, `a = b++` are two *operations*: 1) `b++`, a post-increment operation that results in the value **before** the increment was done; 2) `a = <result from b++>`, an assignment  that stores the result of previous point in `a` || difference between `b++` and `++b`: the first one results in the value **before** incrementing; the second results in the value **after** incrementing (`b` will always be incremented) || Also note that `a = b; b = b + 1;` is not always the correct replacement: the assignment is done after the incrementing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule to remember is: **Think from left to right**.

```java
int a = 2;
int b = 4;
a = b++; // First assign b to a, then increment b.
// Here a=4, b=5
a = ++b; // Cannot set a to ++. First increment b, then assing the incremented value to a.
// Here a=6, b=6
```

Comment: Glad to see it heps. In confusing or hard to remember situations like that, I tend to *put a rule to remember*. This always works for me.

Comment: @user85421: Yup, you are right. Precedence is first of course! My rule here is valid only for this (increment operator) context. Maybe I should edit my answer to prevent misunderstanding.

Comment: My *rule* here is not a real rule of course and the operator precedence is well defined. My intention is to put a *heuristic* to help remember something confusing.

Answer (score 3):

pre increment: `a = ++b` is equivalent to `b = b + 1; a = b;`

post increment: `a = b++` is equivalent to `a = b; b = b + 1;`